Is Exponentiation in $FP$?
I am seeing conflicting answers on this question and I could really use some clarification on it. Constructing an algorithm which computes $f[a,b]=a^b$ can be done naively through repeated multiplication: this leads to $b$ multiplications of the number $a$. Since multiplication can be done in polynomial time and we're performing a polynomial number of multiplications, we seem to have constructed a polynomial-time algorithm to compute $a^b$ and therefore exponentiation is in $FP$.
However, I've seen many people say that it's not, and for two different reasons: 1) the output grows exponentially and 2) for real-valued inputs we can't compute the answer to arbitrary precision in polynomial time. As for 1) I see why this would take exponential space to compute, but not exponential time. This argument seems weak because it means every algorithm that uses exponential space can't perform in polynomial time. For 2) similarly this makes no sense to me -- we define complexity classes over natural number inputs, correct? And the result of $a^b$ for natural numbers $a$ and $b$ is a natural number so arbitrary precision is irrelevant.
Am I missing something? Can someone clarify whether exponentiation is in $FP$, and if not, why the repeated multiplication algorithm I described does not run in polynomial time? (I've tested it for $2^n$ with $n$ going from 1 to 100 and evaluation time does indeed increase linearly).


the output grows exponentially in value, but not in the number of digits. 2) for real values, we can compute to a fixed precision in polynomial time.


The problem with the argument in your first paragraph is that the size $|n|$ of a number $n$ is typically proportional to $\lg n$, because that is how many symbols you need to represent $n$ in a base other than unary. But ...

If you just multiply $a$ together $b$ times, this performs exponentially many multiplications measured in terms of $|b|$
If you try to use a smarter algorithm like exponentiation by squaring, which takes a number of multiplications proportional to $|b|$, each step will be doubling the size of the $a$ that gets multiplied (by itself). So even though the multiplication steps are polynomial to perform, they are performed on exponentially growing inputs relative to the original $|a|$.

So, that is why the argument breaks down.
On Turing machines, it just is the case that any algorithm that uses exponential space also uses exponential time, because it takes that much time just to write down the output, or intermediate values. You can write to at most one distinct tape cell per step. A cost model that disagreed with that for exponentiation would presumably be doing something a bit fishy, like letting you 'write' increasingly large things down with each step.

Thank you. So does this mean that for a function to be in $FP$, its time has to scale at worst logarithmically with $n$, since $|n|$ scales as $\log(n)$, i.e. $n$ scales as $2^n$?

I've never seen people talk about $FP$ before, so I'm not certain. But elsewhere they typically consider the string length of the input as the base of the complexity, and the value of a number is exponential in its string length, yes.

Also, I think if you instead consider unary, where the size equals the value, you will probably be in something like the second situation above. Each step of repeated multiplication, you are doing a multiplication of $a$ and $a^i$. In just the last step, you are doing a multiply with $a^{(b-1)}$, whose unary size is exponential in $b$ (unless $a$ is $0$ or $1$).

If people don't talk about $FP$, what complexity class do people use to describe polynomial-time algorithms?

My experience is that most people just don't talk about the classes for function problems, only for decision problems. Maybe sometimes people are saying $P$ when technically they should say $FP$, though.
